# How does this code print only unique characters from arguments? (Code Logic)

Tags: c

Checklist:

- This program takes two strings and displays, without doubles, the
  characters that appear in either one of the strings.
- The display will be in the order characters appear in the command
  line, and will be followed by a \n.
- If the number of arguments is not 2, the program displays \n.

Code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int used[255] = {0};
        int i = 1, j = 0;
        if(argc == 3)
        {
            while(i < 3)
            {
                j = 0;
                while(argv[i][j])
                {
                    if(!used[(unsigned char)argv[i][j]])
                    {
                    used[(unsigned char)argv[i][j]] = 1;
                        write(1, &argv[i][j], 1);
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        return (0);
    }
```

I understand argument passing part that
argv[0] is the program name,argv[1] is the second string in the string array argv, and strings are character arrays so argv[1][0] is the first character in the second string, argv[1][1] is the second character in the second string and so on.

but how does the below part works `how is it printing unique characters only once from both arguments?`

```
                j = 0;    
                while(argv[i][j])//while argv[i][j] != '\0'
                {
                    if(!used[(unsigned char)argv[i][j]])
                    {
                    used[(unsigned char)argv[i][j]] = 1;
                        write(1, &argv[i][j], 1);
                    }
                    j++;
                }
```

I cannot get the logic. Somebody, who is a C expert, please help me to understand the logic. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code statement by statement in a debugger, while monitoring variables and their values? If you do that while tracing the progress using pen and paper, perhaps the logic becomes clearer?

Comment: `used[255]` is off-by-one - it should be `used[256]` otherwise you get an out-of-bounds array access when the input contains byte 255.

Comment: Thank you Paul Hankin- I will modify the code.

Comment: Some programmer dude - yes I did. I use vscode and my debugging did not work because input is given once the execution starts not before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!used[(unsigned char)argv[i][j]])
```

This is using the char as an index in the array. So for example everytime you get the char 'e' it will check the index 101 in the array and see if it's been used already. Basically it's directly mapping ASCII values to an array. https://theasciicode.com.ar/

It's perhaps easier to understand if you break the code up a bit:

```
int index = argv[i][j]; //Use the character's ASCII value as an index.
if(used[index] == 0) //If this character has NOT appeared before
{
    used[index] = 1; //Mark this index as "used"
    //do stuff with unique character.
}
```

Comment: That's a very good point sir irk, could you please elaborate a little bit more? I have an integer array named used[255] with 255 integer space allocated and filled them with zeros. If my arguments are "hello" "world"  for example how will take only first l and not take the second l? also may I know what is the line used[(unsigned char)argv[i][j]] = 1; doing? Many thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully make it clearer what's going on. The reason you don't get the second "l" is because that's exactly what the "used[255]" array is for. used[(unsigned char)argv[i][j]] = 1 is marking that index as "used" meaning that character has appeared. Then the next loop through it checks used[108] (108 being the ascii value of "l") and see's that it's a 1 so it skips over it.

Comment: Thank you very much sir irk. I appreciate your help!